# Is it possible to include / exclude a list of files by refid in ant?

Tags: java, ant

We currently have an ant task that contains something similar to the following:

```
     <filelist dir="${css.dir}" id="ordered_css">
        <file name="interface/foo.css" />
        <file name="pages/monkey.css" />
        <file name="pages/ninja.css" />
        <file name="pages/sidebar.css" />
        <file name="pages/bar.css" />
        <file name="pages/baz.css" />
        <file name="pages/robot.css" />
     </filelist>

     <patternset id="exclude_css">
        <exclude name="interface/foo.css" />
        <exclude name="pages/monkey.css" />
        <exclude name="pages/ninja.css" />
        <exclude name="pages/sidebar.css" />
        <exclude name="pages/bar.css" />
        <exclude name="pages/baz.css" />
        <exclude name="pages/robot.css" />
     </patternset>
```

The task then references the patternset here:

```
 <fileset dir="${css.dir}" id="stuff_css" includes="*/stuff/*.css">
    <patternset refid="exclude_css" />
 </fileset>
```

And further down, it references the fileset here:

```
<concat destfile="build/all.css" append="false" force="yes">
    <filelist refid="ordered_css" />
    <fileset refid="stuff_css" />
</concat>
```

**Is there a way to consolidate the two lists of files into one type that can be referenced in both places?** So far I haven't been able to figure out a way, since the patternset contains excludes.  I was hoping for a way to simply create a list of files and include or exclude the referenced list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `property` can by used by both if you use the [`filelist files`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filelist.html) and [`patternset excludes`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/patternset.html) attributes.

```
<property name="css_files" 
          value="interface/foo.css
                 pages/monkey.css 
                 pages/ninja.css 
                 pages/sidebar.css
                 pages/bar.css
                 pages/baz.css
                 pages/robot.css"/>

<filelist id="ordered_css" dir="${css.dir}" files="${css_files}"/>

<patternset id="exclude_css" excludes="${css_files}"/>
```